# Can a striped lock be used to synchronize a map?

Tags: java, synchronization, maps

I don't know why I can't get my head around this question.

I see examples on the internet where people talk about using striped locking to synchronize a map. The idea is to use multiple locks to allow for more concurrency, while retaining correctness. But is an approach like this actually correct?

I believe that the idea is to have one lock per bucket, the same thing that `ConcurrentHashMap` does under the hood, but how can one achieve such a feat given the fact the the mapping `key -> bucket` is an internal `Map` implementation detail, and is not actually possible to match it from the outside of the `Map`?

Take this example:

```
public void concurrentMethod(String key) {
    val lock = stripedLock.get(key))
    lock.lock()
    // do work on map[key]
    lock.unlock()
}
```

there's no guarantee that `stripedLocks.get(key)` will return the same lock for 2 keys that will end up in the same bucket. So, as far as I can tell, this is not correct and the synchronization doesn't actually work.

Is my reasoning wrong here? Can an approach like this lead to correct synchronization?

Comment: So your idea is to have an implementation similar to ConcurrentHashMap without developing a Map from the ground up?

Comment: The idea is to synchronize some composite map operation to make it atomic from the outside. For example, if I'm not reading it wrong, this https://www.baeldung.com/java-lock-stripping claims to be doing what I'm asking in my question.

Comment: That Baeldung article seems to be flawed because you cannot use a striped lock in a thread-safe way around `HashMap` (have created an [issue there](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/issues/12096)), or probably more generally around any map whose implementation you cannot control. For example `HashMap` has a field for tracking the total size; using a striped lock for insertions would mean that write access to that field is not properly synchronized. But if you can control the map implementation and know the mapping from key to bucket, then it might be possible to use a striped lock (I assume)

Comment: Nevermind, my comment was partially wrong. You could probably also use a striped lock if you want to synchronize usage of collection entries, but don't have to synchronize access on the collection itself, for example because it is immutable.

Comment: @Marcono1234 I don't truly understand why you say your comment is wrong; the second point of you issue post on GitHub is exactly the same thing that I also believe to be wrong in their implementation, and the reason of why I don't think a striped lock can be used to synchronize access the map entries. That's why I've asked the question: I don't think it's correct, but some posts on the internet claim it's possible like that Baeldung article.

Comment: In the Baeldung article they use the striped lock to synchronize access and modification of the collection itself (which is broken). But let's assume you have a `HashMap<String, SimpleDateFormat>` where you guarantee that the map is [safely published](https://shipilev.net/blog/2014/safe-public-construction/#_safe_publication) and not modified; using a striped lock for access to the `SimpleDateFormat` instances would be thread-safe (should prefer `DateTimeFormatter` though), assuming that the `HashMap` internally does not modify its state on value retrieval (unlike `LinkedHashMap(..., true)`).

Comment: @Marcono1234 even in that example, there would be no point in using striped locking, as using the `SimpleDateFormat` itself as lock key would be simpler and avoid unintended collisions completely.

Comment: `baeldung.com` strikes again. I strongly recommend to take *everything* on that site with a grain of salt.